# Object map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash-map

I want to make a map object that key is object.

But, JavaScript only allows string as a hash key. (at least before ECMAScript6 comes?)

So, I tried to write auxiliary functions to emulate, hash-ish (but actually linear search).
Are there any suggestions on improvement?

```
var tabInfo = {};
var tabInfoKey = 0;

function getTabInfoItem(tab) {
  console.log("getTabInfoItem", tab);
  for(var key in tabInfo) {
    if(tabInfo[key].tab === tab) {
      return tabInfo[key].info;
    }
  }
}

function setTabInfoItem(tab, info) {
  console.log("setTabInfoItem", tab, info);
  for(var key in tabInfo) {
    if(tabInfo[key].tab === tab) {
      tabInfo[key] = {
        tab: tab,
        info: info
      };
      return;
    }
  }
  tabInfoKey++;
  tabInfo[tabInfoKey] = {
    tab: tab,
    info: info
  };
}

function deleteTabInfoItem(tab) {
  console.log("deleteInfoItem", tab);
  for(var key in tabInfo) {
    if(tabInfo[key].tab === tab) {
      delete tabInfo[key];
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a [shim](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections)?

Answer (score 5):

I can't see a good use for this, but nonetheless:

- Since you treat tabInfo as a list, why not have it be an array, this way you don't need `tabInfoKey` and you can use `push` instead. Arrays are objects too.
- Don't use console.log for production code
- `tab` is a terrible name, go for either the Spartan `o` or `object`
- `info` is an unfortunate name, perhaps `value` ?
- `tabInfo` is also meh, perhaps `objectMap` ?
- you should have a constructor for this!

Something like this incorporates my feedback:

```
function ObjectMap() {
  this.entries = [];
}

ObjectMap.prototype.get = function( object ) {
  for( var i = 0 , length = this.entries.length ; i < length ; i++ ){
    if( this.entries[i].object === object ){
      return this.entries[i].value;
    }
  }
}

ObjectMap.prototype.set = function( object, value ) {
  //If we can find it, update it
  for( var i = 0 , length = this.entries.length ; i < length ; i++ ){
    if( this.entries[i].object === object ){
      this.entries[i].value = value;
      return;
    }
  }
  //Otherwise, generate an entry    
  this.entries.push( { object : object , value : value } );
}

ObjectMap.prototype.remove = function( object ) {
  for( var i = 0 , length = this.entries.length ; i < length ; i++ ){
    if( this.entries[i].object === object ){
      this.entries.splice( i , 1 );
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

You can then

```
o = new ObjectMap();
o.set( o , "123" );
o.get( o ); //Gives "123"
o.remove( o );
o.get( o ); //Gives nothing
```

Furthermore you should consider whether you want to allow function chaining, right now none of these functions return anything and it seems a shame.